# How to find multiple instances of a class in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I have a UIView class that has a number of subviews of a subclass of UITextField. Is there a way to iterate through a list of classes to find the UITextField subclasses

Answer (score 2):

Yes!

Assuming you are placing the code in an UIView subclass, you can grab an array of subviews...

```
NSArray *sbviews = [self subviews];
NSMutableArray *textFields; //placeholder for your UITextField subclassed objects.

//enumerate through the subview collection and only add objects to the textFields array that are UITextField objects.
for (id anObject in sbviews) {
    if([anObject isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]]){
        [textField addObject: anObject];
    }
}
```

The textField array will now contain all objects that are of kind of class UITextField...

Answer (score 0):

Your UIView class has a subviews array that lists all the subviews you have added to it.  You can iterate thru the array and look for instances (not classes) of UITextField objects.

```
for (UITextField* textField in [someView subviews]) {
    if ([textField isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        // found one, textField really is a UITextField
    }
}
```